# Will std::sort work correctly if I defined a custom compare function for floating number?

Tags: c++, sorting, floating-point

For the issue of the floating precision, I defined my custom compare function for floating numbers:

```
bool cmp(double a, double b)
{
    if(abs(a - b) <= eps) return false;
    return a < b;
}
```

Then I call sort on some array of floating numbers. I've heard that some bad compare function will cause the sort to segment fault. I just wondering will `cmp` work correctly for sort? On one hand, `cmp` satisfied the associating rule. But on the other hand, `cmp(x - eps, x) == false` && `cmp(x, x + eps) == false` doesn't mean `cmp(x - eps, x + eps) == false`.

I didn't use sort directly on floating numbers because what I want to sort is `pair<double, double>`. 
For example:

```
(1,2), (2,1), (2.000000001, 0)
```

I'd like to consider 2 and 2.000000001 as the same and expect the result to be:

```
(1,2), (2.000000001, 0), (2,1)
```

Comment: Using "nearly equal" correctly requires deep knowledge of floating-point math. It is **not** a replacement for understanding what your code is doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::sort` requires a comparer that defines a **strict weak ordering**. This means, among other things, that the following condition must be met:

- We define two items, `a` and `b`, to be **equivalent** (`a === b`) if `!cmp(a, b) && !cmp(b, a)`
- Equivalence is transitive: `a === b` && `b === c` => `a === c`

As you already say in your question, your function `cmp()` does not meet these conditions, so you cannot use your function in `std::sort()`. Not only the result of the algorithm will be unpredictable, which is bad unless you are actually looking for this unpredictability (cf. `randomize`): if you have a few values that are very close to each other, such that any of them compare `true` with some, but `false` with some others, the algorithm might enter an infinite loop.

So the answer is no, you cannot use your function `cmp()` in `std::sort()` unless you want to risk your program freezing.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you bother to make an *approximate* less-than comparison? That makes no sense.

Just sort your array strictly by actual values.

*Then* use your approximate comparison function to determine which of the elements you wish to consider to be equal.

(The equivalent in English would be the infamous "almost better". Think about it.)

Comment: I'd like to sort pair of doubles. If the first equals, I'll compare the second. I think it's a little clumsy to sort the first key and then sort several times for the second key.

Comment: @chyx: All the same - sort the pairs lexicographically first, otherwise you can never have a reliable algorithm that works for all situations. It's the determination of "equivalent" values that's non-trivial, and you won't get around approaching that problem separately and diligently. It's rather delicate. Once you've grouped the first values into equivalence groups, you can sort the second key.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll modify my code. But I'm still curious about whether the `cmp` will fail the sort or not. :-)

Comment: @chyx: even with pairs, you can sort once on the first value, then decide what to consider equivalent, then sort again using a modified first value (so that equivalent values are now equal) 
and the second value. Alternatively, round all values to the nearest multiple of `eps` and then sort, although I suspect that rounding doesn't solve all one-ulp-out issues.

Comment: @SteveJessop Another question: if I let `a = b`, can I be sure that `a < b` will be false after that?

Comment: @chyx: where `a` and `b` are doubles as in the question? You can be sure of that with strict enough IEEE modes, and I think you can be sure of it as far as the C++ standard is concerned. There might be "loose" or "fast" modes which allow cases where `b` is stored in a super-precision floating point register, while `a` is stored in memory. To conform I think such a mode would have to round `b` *down* to `double` before comparing with `a`, but I bet it wouldn't. So maybe it could go wrong in non-conforming compiler modes, *but* I doubt that super-precision situation would come up while sorting.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to define a comparison function for floating point that *groups* similar values. You do so by rounding:

```
bool cmp(double a, double b)
{
    const double eps = 0.0001;
    int a_exp;
    double a_mant = frexp(a, &a_exp); // Between 0.5 and 1.0
    a_mant -= modf(a_mant, eps); // Round a_mant to 0.00001
    a = ldexp(a_mant, a_exp); // Round a to 0.00001 * 10^a_exp
    // and the same for b
    int b_exp;
    double b_mant = frexp(b, &b_exp); 
    b_mant -= modf(b_mant, eps);  
    b = ldexp(b_mant, b_exp);
    // Compare rounded results.
    return a < b;
}
```

Now `cmp(a,b)==true` implies that `a<b`, and `a==b` and `a>b` both imply `cmp(a,b)==false`.